# iOS frequent constraint constant update causing frame rate drop

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, core-animation, frame-rate

I am creating an application with a user interface similar to Tinder's. To recreate this user interface, I've had to employ a `UIPageViewController` embedded in a container view with `UIButton`s laid over the container view. Recreating this UI is expensive and causes my app to drop in frame rate.

[image]

Note the drop in frame rates when swiping to the right page.

Whenever the user scrolls between pages, the overlaid `UIButton`s adjust in size and color based on how much the user has scrolled between pages. This is done by subclassing the `UIPageViewController` as a `UIScrollViewDelegate` and passing the `UIPageViewController`'s `UIScrollView`'s `contentOffset.x` as a percent of the superview's width to a function that adjusts the overlaid buttons accordingly.

```swift
extension PageViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let point = scrollView.contentOffset
        var percentComplete: CGFloat
        percentComplete = abs(point.x - view.frame.size.width)/view.frame.size.width
        if !(point.x > view.frame.width && currentPage == 2) && !(point.x < view.frame.width && currentPage == 0) {
            if point.x < view.frame.width  {
                containerVC.adjustButtons(for: percentComplete, direction: 1)
            } else {
                containerVC.adjustButtons(for: percentComplete, direction: 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The function that adjusts the size and color of my buttons is called every time `scrollViewDidScroll` is called. This is done by referencing how much the `UIPageViewController` has scrolled and adjusting button constraints, image insets, and images accordingly. This function is likely extremely expensive as it is called each time `scrollViewDidScroll` is called, but I am unsure how else to approach the issue.

The end-result is the behavior that I expected, but there is a considerable drop in frame rate at times when a scroll in the `UIPageViewController` is begun.

```swift
func adjustButtons(for percentage: CGFloat, direction: Int) {
    buttonWrapperLeading.constant = (view.frame.width/2 - 38) * percentage
    buttonWrapperTrailing.constant = (view.frame.width/2 - 38) * percentage
    self.profileButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8 * (1-percentage), left: 8 * (1-percentage), bottom: 8 * (1-percentage), right: 8 * (1-percentage))
    self.meetButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8 * percentage, left: 8 * percentage, bottom: 8 * percentage, right: 8 * percentage)
    self.chatButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8)
    let newProfileButtonImage = UIImage(named: "profileSilhouette")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate).image(withTintColor: UIColor.interpolate(from: .darkGray, to: .secondaryColor, with: percentage))
    profileButton.setImage(newProfileButtonImage, for: .normal)
    let newMeetButtonImage = UIImage(named: "meet")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate).image(withTintColor: UIColor.interpolate(from: .secondaryColor, to: .darkGray, with: percentage))
    meetButton.setImage(newMeetButtonImage, for: .normal)
}
```

I am wondering how I could go about this to minimize frame rate dropping. I imagine that the adjustment of constraint constants, as well as setting of button images with a different shade and a different imageInset each time the function is called is likely causing the issue, but I am unsure. I have no clue how else I could recreate this UI without dropping the frame rate.

Here is what Tinder's UI looks like for reference:
[image]

Comment: it's not a standard answer, you may use UIPageViewControllerDelegate to achieve one time animation. Or get the UIPresentationController during the process and perform custom animations.

Answer (score 0):

I would use profiling (Instruments) to get more details about what is causing the frame drop.